# checkoutLineItemsReplace method is not available

Tags: android, shopify

I am using Shopify. I want to update the checkout items with the old checkout id. In Swift and JS checkoutLineItemsReplace method is available. But in Android it is not showing. I am using version 3:3.2.3
Shopify link: https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android